# Reading and writing specific lines using python

Tags: python

I'm working on a small project which involves python. So i'm teaching myself the basics of python. I know how to read and write files using python PDE. But I'm not sure how to read and write specific files. For example I have a text file as follows:

```
234, 645, 876
123, 213
642, 097, 563
cohesive_element node numbers
583,  317,  318,  289,  255
584,  318,  319,  290,  289
585,  319,  320,  291,  290
586,  320,  321,  292,  291
587,  321,  322,  293,  292
elset generate
725, 1032, 1033,  965,  964
726, 1033, 1034,  966,  965
727, 1034, 1035,  967,  966
728, 1035, 1036,  968,  967
```

Here, I need to read the numbers between "cohesive_element node numbers" and "elset generate" and write it in a different text file.
Thanks!

Comment: What is python PDE?

Comment: what did you try so far. It seems a simple if else or better regex

Comment: I don't see how this is a Python-specific question. Just read the file, find the boundaries with regex or a simple search, and write what's in between.

Comment: I suggest that you start with the Pythong Tutorial. It will show you how to read a file. You also need to learn how to break a problem down into smaller pieces. For example, if I were doing this, I would first write a program which opens a file and prints its contents to the screen. Can you do that much?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = open('filename.txt').readlines()
f = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]

indices = [i for i, a in enumerate(f) if a == "cohesive_element node numbers" or a == "elset generate"]

new_data = [map(int, i.split(", ")) for i in f[indices[0]+1:indices[-1]]]
```

Output:

```
[[583, 317, 318, 289, 255],  
[584, 318, 319, 290, 289], 
[585, 319, 320, 291, 290], 
[586, 320, 321, 292, 291], 
[587, 321, 322, 293, 292]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me too. Still don't understand how. I have a lot to learn in python i guess.

Answer (score 0):

can be done like this:

```
to_be_copied = []

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    valid_line = False
    for line in f.readlines():
        if valid_line:
            to_be_copied.append(valid_line)
        # to determine if we are in the 'valid' block
        valid_line = True if 'cohesive_element' in line else False if 'elset' in line else valid_line

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write('\n'.join(valid_lines))
```